# Mobile networks in Poland

Tags: cellphones, internet, poland, mobile-operators

I am preparing my trip to Poland and would like to know in advance which mobile operator should I buy.

Could you please give me links to mobile operators sites, so I could compare prices?

Is there any alternative if I need mobile internet without seeking for a wi-fi hotspot (e.g. a company offers 4G/CDMA/LTE/etc modems)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you have links to polish mobile operators:

- http://www.plus.pl
- http://www.orange.pl
- http://www.t-mobile.pl
- http://www.play.pl

As far as I know all of them have offers of 4G mobile Internet (LTE).

Comment: I see three types of offer: abonament, mix and karta. As far as I understand abonament is a long-term contract. Could you please explain the difference between mix and karta? I need short term (pay-as-yuou-go) contract. Thank you.

Comment: @Putnik you want "karta". Mix is also a long-term contract, but instead of getting invoices like a normal contract, you get a commitment to recharge your phone credit with prepaid vouchers with a certain schedule.

Answer (score 8):

It should be a reply to OPs question in the comments but I don't have 50 reputation yet. If moderators can merge it somehow, please, feel free.

Abonament is a long-term contract.

Karta is pay-as-you-go. It is pre-paid and you charge it by buying and redeeming codes (e.g. in convenience stores and newsstands).

Mix is, well, a mix of two. You pay as you go, but sign a contract on how long you will go.

In your situation go for "karta".